# Pubnub GCM Notification not being pushed Javascript

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I currently have the following code that's working for iOS-APNS, but not for Android:

```
function makeMessageNew() {
  var pubnub = new PubNub({
      publishKey : 'pub',
      subscribeKey : 'sub'
  })
  var pushPayload = {
    "pn_apns": {
        "aps" : {
            "alert": "This is a notification",
            "badge": 2,
            "sound": "melody"
        },
    },
    "pn_gcm": {
        "data" : {
            "title":"Hello",
            "message":"This is a notification"
        }
    },
    "pn_debug":true
  }
  pubnub.publish({ message: pushPayload, channel:"channel" }, function (status) {
      console.log(pushPayload);
      console.log(status);
  })
}
```

In my Channel-pndebug, it tells me that:

> "Devices found for push notification apns: 2 gcm: 1 mpns: 0"

I know that my device is registered to the channel, and I've sent notifications before which means that my keys, etc. are right.

However, even though the notification works for iOS, and I receive it, it doesn't show up on Android-GCM. Can anyone tell me why?

Here's my Payload Data:

```
{
  "pn_apns": {
    "aps": {
      "alert": "This is a notification",
      "badge": 1
    },
    "sound": "melody"
  },
  "pn_gcm": {
    "data": {
      "title": "Push Demo",
      "message": "This is a notification"
    }
  },
  "pn_debug": true
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you got this code from? It looks like there are some errors so I just want to confirm whether this is your code or some code you pulled from an example/docs.

Comment: The majority of my code is from - https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/mobile-gateway#Publish_example_1. I wasn't sure how to pass data for the GCM part so I copied whatever I was able to find online (there wasn't much :) )

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: OK, it's good. I am never used to the way we do push notifications in JavaScript, but all looks good. So the only thing that it could be at this point is that the message is being received in your Android device but not being displayed. Can you tell me if you receive the GCM when the app is running in foreground?

Comment: Also, just wondering if you can move to our JavaScript SDK v4? We just released it this week and it is much nicer. Not sure which Android SDK you are using but also, v4 is much nicer.

Comment: How would I check that? When I run the function, and keep the app open on my android device, nothing changes/appears on the device.

Comment: Haha, I can definitely check that out right now.

Comment: You might want to submit full details to [PubNub Support](http://pubnub.com/support): code attached as files, etc. Also include link to this thread.

Comment: [Android SDK v4](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android/pubnub-android-sdk-v4). [JavaScript SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-v4). And you can [enable logging for Android](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android/pubnub-android-sdk-troubleshooting-guide-sdk-v4) and send complete log file to support.

Comment: Right, I've updated to V4 of Javascript SDK, and the same issue persists. Our Android Developer has left for today, so it will not be possible to check that out. Is there any other way I can troubleshoot this issue and ensure it's not a problem on my side?

Comment: You can try following [this mobile push troubleshooting guide](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/1127/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues), but sounds like you might have already. But give it a look and make sure you have gone through all of it. If you still don't know the issue, send all important data you collect to support.

Comment: How are you handling the messages on the client side, could you add that Android code to your question?

Comment: @The_Curry_Man did u find the solution?